# How to display all the result using Access VBA Select Query?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am running the below code to run sql and display the product within the messagebox. This works fine. My question is if I want to display all the products at the same time so that I can copy or export the result out just like if I would run the Access Query and it would give me all the products displayed. What can I do here? Do I need to re-write the whole query or just change the for loop and msgbox to something else?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rcnt As Integer
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT jd.Product FROM Consumption_JobDetails 
AS jd " & _"INNER JOIN Consumption_JobRepairCentre AS jc ON jd.jobnumber = jc.jobnumber;")

rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst

For rcnt = 0 To rs.RecordCount
MsgBox (rs.Fields("Product").Value)
rs.MoveNext
Next rcnt
```

Comment: Writing data to a message box will not allow copy or export. Depending on how many values are retrieved, MsgBox might not even be able to display all. Build a query or report object for export. Or use Excel automation to write recordset to worksheet.

Comment: Code as posted would not work because line ending break is not correct. I am guessing there was a copy/paste snafu.

Comment: It was a copy/paste of code.  How to build a Query like this?  Any example or solution for this one?

Comment: There is nothing extraordinary about joining tables in query. Open query builder and build query. Basic Access functionality. If you need a tutorial, I am sure there are many on web.

Answer (score 0):

Use concatenation to build a string of values for display in MsgBox.

```
Do While Not rs.EOF
    strP = strP & rs!Product & ", " 'or use vbCrLf instead of ", ".
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox strP
```

Comment: I declared strP as string and ran this code.  It gave me error - Runtime error 3265, Item not found.

Comment: Again this code will generate output within Msgbox and will not display as if I run a Access select query.  Is there anyway I can display my results just like simple Access select query?

Comment: Sorry, I acctidentally added an 's' to Product field name. Build a query or report object. Code can open query or report. Basic Access functionality.

Comment: Access can run a stored query, I know that.  The reason I want to run select SQL statement is because I want to provide dynamic input to filter this query like select product from table where center = InputCenterNumberManually.  Using the stored query I can have only 1 kind of filter and I can't change the center number dynamically.

Comment: I resolved this by using Querydef and assigning my query there.  Thank you!

Comment: Or use a dynamic parameterized query object. Alternatively, apply filter to report when opening. QueryDef code is usually a last ditch act of desperation when nothing else is adequate. Instead of repeatedly creating/deleting tables or queries, I prefer 'temp table' - table is permanent but records are temporary

Comment: What do you mean by can have 'only 1 kind of filter' and 'can't change the center number'? Certainly can have multiple criteria and the inputs can certainly be dynamic.